# Duplicate function execution with modules in JS

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have a two files: `main.js` and `functions.mjs`

In HTML write the call:

```
<script type="module" src="./src/modules/qr/main.js<?php echo "?v=" . $version; ?>"></script>
```

In main.js, I have this code, I only share the code that I think is relevant...

```
import {
  searchDevice,
  isNumber,
  outputMessageFunction,
  isURL,
  recoveryDevicesInDB,
  saveDeviceInDB,
  addDeviceToTableFunction,
  deleteDevice,
} from "./functions.mjs";
export let DEVICES_GLOBAL = {};


recoveryDevicesInDB()
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
          DEVICES_GLOBAL[data[key].idDevice] = data[key];
          addDeviceToTableFunction(data[key]);
        });
        if (idDevice && !data[idDevice]) {
          searchDevice(idDevice)
            .then((dataDevice) => {
              saveDeviceInDB(dataDevice)
                .then((status) => {
                  if (status == true) {
                    DEVICES_GLOBAL[dataDevice.idDevice] = dataDevice;
                  }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              outputMessageFunction(error, "red");
            });
        }
      } else if (idDevice) {
        searchDevice(idDevice)
          .then((data) => {
            // Recuperar el dispositivo por su idDevice
            saveDeviceInDB(data)
              .then((status) => {
                console.log(status);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            outputMessageFunction(error, "red");
          });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      outputMessageFunction(error, "red");
    });
```

And finally, in functions.mjs i only shared the code that I think is relevant.

```
import { DEVICES_GLOBAL } from "./main.js";

function openDatabase() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open("qrList", 1);

    request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result;
      const objectStore = db.createObjectStore("dispositivos", {
        keyPath: "idDevice",
      });
    };

    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result;
      resolve(db);
    };

    request.onerror = (event) => {
      reject(event.target.error);
    };
  });
}

export async function recoveryDevicesInDB() {
  try {
    const db = await openDatabase();
    const transaction = db.transaction(["devices"], "readonly");
    const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("devices");
    const getRequest = objectStore.getAll();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
        const devices = event.target.result;
        if (devices) {
          resolve(devices);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      };

      getRequest.onerror = (error) => {
        console.error("Error al recuperar dispositivos:", error.target.error);
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al abrir la base de datos:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is recover all the information from an indexedDB table to later translate it into HTML table.

The problem is that the execution of this function is duplicated, as an example, write a console.log("test") inside this function and in the console it appears twice, or the information is directly duplicated in the HTML

[image: rows duplicates]

The problem arises when I needed to use the DEVICES GLOBAL variable from main.js in function.mjs.

I exported the variable and imported it in function.mjs and since then the execution of the function has been duplicated, when I remove the two lines "import and export" from the two files, everything works normally but I still need to access the DEVICES_GLOBAL information in functions.mjs

Comment: You have circular imports. `main.js` imports from `functions.mjs`, and `functions.mjs` imports from `main.js`.

Comment: So `main.js` runs twice -- first when you load it from HTML, and again when it gets imported from `functions.mjs`. This isn't a problem if the module just defines functions, but if it executes code at top-level it runs twice.

Comment: So how could I import the {DEVICES_GLOBAL} variable into functions.mjs or otherwise how could I handle this variable within functions.mjs?

Comment: OK, I feel like a fool.

Just declare the variable in functions.mjs and export it to main.js